# Complex query in SQL

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I have a quite complex query (at least for my beginner level), so I hope anybody can help me with it.

Here it is an example of my table:

```
Device nr    type   state   I1     I2
    1          A     on     20     10
    1          A     off    20     10
    1          B     on     19     8
    1          B     off    20     10
    1          C     on     21     12
    1          C     off    20     10
    2          A     on     21     9
    2          A     off    20     10
    2          B     on     18     7
    2          B     off    20     10
    2          C     on     20     9
    2          C     off    20     10
    3          A     on     17     11
    3          A     off    20     10
    3          B     on     20     11
    3          B     off    20     10
    3          C     on     19     10
    3          C     off    20     10
    1          A     on     20     10
    1          A     off    20     10
    1          B     on     19     8
    1          B     off    20     10
    1          C     on     21     12
    1          C     off    20     10
    2          A     on     21     9
    2          A     off    20     10
    2          B     on     18     7
    2          B     off    20     10
    2          C     on     20     9
    2          C     off    20     10
    3          A     on     17     11
    3          A     off    20     10
    3          B     on     20     11
    3          B     off    20     10
    3          C     on     19     10
    3          C     off    20     10
```

My question is how could I group and count the devices that are considered ok.

Device is ok when all types within the device (A,B and C) are ok.

And type A or B or C is ok when its `"on" state` has `I1>19` and `I2<11`.

With my limited SQL experience I know how to set conditions like:

```
select (*) from myTalbe
where (I1>19 and I2<11)
```

But how can I make it count when `A` and `B` and `C` are ok and all have same `Device nr`?

An example of a desired output would be something like:

```
Device nr    OKcount
   1            15
   2            9
   3            22
```

So, for example, this ouput would say that there are 15 devices with number 1 that have A and B and C ok **within the device**

Comment: Can you explain how you got the "OKcount" in your desired output?

Comment: The numbers in my desired output are just an example, I wrote them manually, they dont mean anything, just example

Comment: Out of interest, what is the primary key on the table?

Comment: well, I did not want to make the post bigger, but there is actually another column, called just ID which is the primary key.there are in fact some other columns, not posted. Just posted the interesting part.

Comment: In your table you have two rows with Device 1, Type A, state on. In your case, values of I1 and I2 are the same, but in general they need not to be I assume? In that case, if one set could be OK and one not. What is then status of Device 1, Type A?

Comment: yes in my example table (due to copy/paste) Device1, type A, state on are the same but they dont have to, they can be whatever number. I have to think about it like "independent" devices, even though they have same number. I mean if the first Device 1 has A,B,C ok, then we have one Device 1 ok, if the next Device 1 has again A,B, C ok then we have two Devices 1 ok...and so on. Each device is independent

Comment: But which A,B,C belongs then to which device 1?

Comment: I dont think the table need more info, just that each type A,B, C belongs to the device on its same row...I hope that is enough to explain it

Comment: @newPyUser, the primary key for a database table is definitely 'interesting'!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select "Device nr", count(*) as OKcount FROM (
    select DISTINCT "Device nr", type from Table1
    where (I1>19 and I2<11) and state="on"
)
group by "Device nr"
having OKcount = 3
```

Sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/32d81/4

Comment: Maybe I can't get it quite right from the question. If you say, that all lines - are separate devices, than this is correct. If not - you need something to tell one device from another.

Comment: Or are you trying to say that you have to count only devices that have "ok" for all types?

Comment: sorry its me, probably im not clear enough...each `device` is represented by 6 rows (2 for A (on, off) 2 for B (on, off) 2 for C (on,off) ), im only interested in `on` lines (so just 3 lines). Now, one independent device is ok if its 3 types ABC are ok. So if reading the table from top to bottom we could have have (device1 A ok device1 B ok device1 C ok) then increase OKcount in Device 1 by 1. But if we find (device1 A ok device1 B NOTok device1 C ok) then dont increase OKcount for device1

Comment: @newPyUser I've updated my answer. I doubt this is the best approach, but still should do the trick. First we are getting all distinct devices, and they group them with only those who got 3 members (like Clément Séveillac suggested).

Comment: In your solution, where or when is OKcount reseted? I mean If I find for example (Device2 A ok, Device2 B ok, Device2 C NOT ok), here OKcount=2, however, for the next device it should be reseted to 0, if I am not wrong.

Comment: You don't have to reset anything. After grouping you have Device2 with OKcount=2 and DeviceN with OKcount=3, `having OKcount=3` will return you only those with OKcount=3

Answer (score 1):

To finalize the cool approach of konart's answer:

```
select "Device nr" from (select "Device nr", count(*) as OKcount from Table1
where (I1>19 and I2<11) and state="on"
group by "Device nr") where OKcount = 3
```

Comment: that could do it, I will give it a try

Comment: @Clément Séveillac this way will work if we are sure there won't be the case when we have Device1A and two Device1B, for example. We will have count = 3 anyway.

Comment: Sure! By the way if input might have two "A" with status = "on", we need more details on validation criteria then :)